# Iterate all elements in std::vector using c-style API

Tags: c++, stl

According to “Item 16. Know how to pass vector and string data to legacy APIs.” of Effective STL of Scott Meyers:

It is safe to use c-style API to access all the elements of vector,
since vectors are guaranteed to have the same underlying memory layout as arrays.

```
//example 1, do sth to all elements in vector using c-style API
void doSomething(const int *pInts, size_t numlnts);

vector<int> v;   
if (!v.empty()) {
    doSomething(&v[0], v.size()); 
}

//example 2, init vector with c-style API
size_t fillArray(double *pArray, size_t arraySize); 

vector<double> vd(maxNumDoubles);    
vd.resize(fillArray(&vd[0], vd.size()));
```

To use vector together with c-style API, is there any requirement for the element type T in c++ standard?

Is it always safe if T is a build-in type or POD type?

Comment: Note that a C-style API does not mean the _implementation_ of the function must be in C. It could be implemented in Haskell, Java, or... C++.

Comment: With `c++11` you can avoid the `empty` check and just use the [`data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) function to get the pointer to the beginning of the array.

Comment: @JamesAdkison data() may return NULL if the the vector has had no reason to allocate underlying storage yet.  If you write your loop correctly, this can be ok, but in this post we cannot see that loop.

Comment: @qexyn An empty `vector` will also have size `0` but it is still the correct way to get a pointer to the array and less error prone than `&myVector[0]`. Whether the function accepting the pointer to an array and the array's length properly handles a null pointer or a zero length array is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no requirement for the element type T.  The vector will allocate memory so that each element in the vector consumes sizeof(T) bytes.  When you write a loop that iterates over the underlying array via pointer arithmetic (or indexing, which is pointer arithmetic under the hood), the exact same element size is used (sizeof(T)) during the increment/decrement.

However, assuming that you will be reading/writing the underlying data array in true C, then you will face limitation in the sense that C++ class types like std::string, MyCustomClass, etc. cannot be used as T because it will be impossible for your C functions to accept such types safely.  As long as T is a type that both C++ and C languages know the storage size of (i.e. both can use sizeof(T) without compilation problems), then you will be in good shape.